# Fetch/Find child collection using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am newbie in MongoDB. I am having some problem for nested collection. Suppose I have 3 different collections in mongodb. (1) classes (2) subjects and (3) chapter.

Classes contain various class name, subjects contain different subject name for a particular class and chapters contain different subject name for a particular subject.

Using mongoose I can fetch/find parents collection of chapters like following:

```js
ChapterModel.find({})
  .limit(1)
  .populate([
    { path: "classId", model: ClassModel },
    { path: "subjectId", model: SubjectModel }
  ]);
```

which gives the following result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5de6a660a5f6a42060d532cd",
    "name": "Physical Quantities and Their Measurements",
    "subjectId": {
      "_id": "5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c5",
      "classId": "5de6a65fa5f6a42060d532c4",
      "name": "Physics"
    },
    "classId": {
      "_id": "5de6a65fa5f6a42060d532c4",
      "name": "IX"
    }
  }
]
```

But I couldn't find any method to fetch child of class in following way:

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c5"),
    "name": "IX",
    "subjects": [
      {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c6"),
        "name": "Physics",
        "classId": ObjectId("5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c5"),
        "chapters": [
          {
            "_id" : ObjectId('5c09fb04ff03a672a26fb23a'),
            "name": Physical Quantities and Their Measurements",
            "classId": ObjectId("5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c5"),
            "subjectId": ObjectId("5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c6"),
          },
          {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c6"),
            "name": "Motion",
            "classId": ObjectId("5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c5"),
            "subjectId": ObjectId("5de6a660a5f6a42060d532c6"),
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is their any way like populate to find all nested children or collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) features of mongoose.

One way to solve your problem is designing the schemas and models like this:
(Note that I used Course name instead of Class since it is a reserved keyword in javascript)

course.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

courseSchema.virtual("subjects", {
  ref: "Subject",
  foreignField: "course",
  localField: "_id"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);
```

subject.js

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const subjectSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: String,
    course: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Course"
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

subjectSchema.virtual("chapters", {
  ref: "Chapter",
  foreignField: "subject",
  localField: "_id"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Subject", subjectSchema);
```

chapter.js:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const chapterSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  subject: {
    type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Subject"
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Chapter", chapterSchema);
```

Note that the virtual keyword means [populate virtual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals).
I chose this solution, because otherwise we should have keep an additional field called subjects in course schema where we needed to keep an array of subject ids, (and chapters field in subject schema).

With these schemas, you can use the following query to get the result you wanted:

```js
const Course = require("../models/course");

router.get("/courses", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Course.find({}).populate({
    path: "subjects",
    populate: { path: "chapters" }
  });

  res.send(result);
});
```

In case you have difficulty to test, here are the other routes to create course, subject and chapters:

```js
const Subject = require("../models/subject");
const Chapter = require("../models/chapter");
const Course = require("../models/course");

router.post("/courses", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Course.create(req.body);
  res.send(result);
});

router.post("/subjects", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Subject.create(req.body);
  res.send(result);
});

router.post("/chapters", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Chapter.create(req.body);
  res.send(result);
});

router.get("/courses", async (req, res) => {
  const result = await Course.find({}).populate({
    path: "subjects",
    populate: { path: "chapters" }
  });

  res.send(result);
});
```

First I created a post with this body: (giving a course id 5de6c047856efe390cbf665d)

```
{
    "name": "IX"
}
```

Then I created a subject using this 5de6c047856efe390cbf665d course id with this body: (giving a subject id 5de6c0d7856efe390cbf665e)

```
{
    "name": "Physics",
    "course": "5de6c047856efe390cbf665d"
}
```

Then using this subject id 5de6c0d7856efe390cbf665e, I created two chapters using these:

```
{
    "name": "Physical Quantities and Their Measurements",
    "subject": "5de6c0d7856efe390cbf665e"
}
```

```
{
    "name": "Motion",
    "subject": "5de6c0d7856efe390cbf665e"
}
```

And the result is:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5de6c047856efe390cbf665d",
        "name": "IX",
        "__v": 0,
        "subjects": [
            {
                "_id": "5de6c0d7856efe390cbf665e",
                "name": "Physics",
                "course": "5de6c047856efe390cbf665d",
                "__v": 0,
                "chapters": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5de6c123856efe390cbf665f",
                        "name": "Physical Quantities and Their Measurements",
                        "subject": "5de6c0d7856efe390cbf665e",
                        "__v": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5de6c136856efe390cbf6660",
                        "name": "Motion",
                        "subject": "5de6c0d7856efe390cbf665e",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "id": "5de6c0d7856efe390cbf665e"
            }
        ],
        "id": "5de6c047856efe390cbf665d"
    }
]
```

Comment: why it generating an extra id field?

Comment: @RejaulKarim id value is the same value as _id, it seems to appear because of toJSON. But it is not a big issue I think. I wil comment here later to remove that _id.

Comment: @RejaulKarim  add id: false option in the schema definitions like this: `{
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
 id: false
}`

Comment: You saved my ass!!! Very well explaination.